# What is the difference among these sentences

Tags: prepositions

what is the difference among the next four sentences?

Sentence 1. She didn't get married until she was 35.

Sentence 2. She got married until she was 35.

Sentence 3. She can't leave until she has finished.

Sentence 4. She can leave until she finishes.

Comment: #2 and #4 are invalid. #1 and #3 look to be syntactically the same to me (they're both fine).

Comment: #4 *She can leave until she finishes (doing something, then she needs to come back)* is fine.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Even if you could make a case for #4 being grammatical in certain contexts, it's so "unusual" I think most native speakers would look for a different way of expressing the intended sense. I can only read the full context of 2 out of the 5 instances of [*I can leave until*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+can+leave+until%22) in Google Books, and neither of them match OP's context. On the other hand, there are nearly 10,000 instances of the "natural" ***negated*** version [*I **can't** leave until*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+can%27t+leave+until%22)

Comment: I think AlanCarmack is refering to a case when someone says "she needs to come back when she has finished" doing whatever she is doing or going to do

Comment: @fumblefingers, I agree that there is a substantial bias in usage, which is reversed if you replace "leave" with "stay" (see Ngram). My point is that it **is** grammatically correct, it's just not particularly useful. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+stay+until%2Ccan%27t+stay+until%2C+can+leave+until%2C+can%27t+leave+until&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20stay%20until%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20stay%20until%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20leave%20until%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20leave%20until%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JavaLatte: Well, the long and short of it is even a competent native speaker would need to think long and hard before coming up with a "natural" context where they could reasonably defend *[subject] can leave until [some future time]*. So imho it's not just "not particularly useful" for a learner to be aware that the usage could in principle be "grammatical". It's effectively *counterproductive* information, since they'll have practically no chance of ever being able to use it "correctly" (but they might well fall into the trap of trying to use it in contexts where it *doesn't* work).

Comment: ...btw - almost all the hits in your NGram for *can leave until* (if not every single one) don't match OP's context. They're things like *That job we can leave until later*, or *Nobody can leave until we all agree*. The figures in my Google Books search above are overwhelming, and *aren't* significantly affected by "accidental collocations".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think I understand the problem. The key is to look at **leave** rather than **can** when evaluating whether it's an event or a state. **leave** is an event, but **not leave** is a state. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Manuel Hernandez: Congratulations on managing to ask a question where it seems native speakers are better at just *using* "until" correctly than they are at explaining *why* not every construction that seems credible to you might not in fact be acceptable! I'm not disagreeing with JavaLatte's answer, but I will be very interested to see if someone else can explain things more fully. I'd upvote this question *twice* if I could! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks I do my best to not sound stupid when asking questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use **until** about something that extends over a period of time up to some event.

Getting married is regarded as an instantaneous event, being married or not being married is something that extends over a period of time.

Sentence 1 is about not being married, which extends over a period of time, so you can use it with until.

Sentence 2 is about getting married, which is an event, so you can't use it with until.

**leave** (in the sense depart) is an event, but **not leave** (in the sense stay) is a state that can extend over a period of time so sentence 3 is valid but sentence 4 is not.

**leave** (in the sense leave alone) is valid over a period of time, so this is valid:

> You can leave it until later

Your sentence 4 would be valid if used **stay**, which is valid over a period of time, rather than **leave**:

> She can stay until she finishes

Comment: So can I say: "you can use the computer until you finish that game" meaning "you need to stop using the computer when you finish that game"

Comment: Certainly you can. It's grammatically correct, and the meaning is sensible.

Comment: which one would be correct  " she got married by her 35" or " she got married by she was 35" in order to mean she got married before she turned 35

Comment: @Mrt - Neither of those is grammatically correct.  "She was married by 35" is how I would phrase it.

Comment: @Mrt, remember, **got married** is the event.  Like **until**, you can't use **by** with an event. You could say "she got married by a priest" or "she was married by 35" or "she was married by the age of 35", or "she got married before she was 35".

Comment: Following the edit, I've cancelled my downvote. But I'm not sure we've got the whole story here, so for the time being I'm withholding my *upvote*. I know "instinctively" how *until* can and can't be used, although I'm not consciously aware of "the rules". Nevertheless, my gut feel is there are probably multiple factors in play, and I suspect ***negation*** is at least as important as "stative/dynamic verb", if not more so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, agreed. My answer is a hueristic rather than a rule.

Answer (score 0):

The first one means she **was not** married, but when she turned 35 *she was* married.

> The second one means she **was** married, but when she turned 35 she *was not*.

Also the second one is not grammatically correct. You would say it like;

> She **was** married until she was 35.